# Unable to get onDragStart Event on React for HTML5 Drag and Drop

Tags: html, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I am creating a basic application in ReactJs to implement the basic HTML5 Drag and Drop functionality. The issue I am facing is, my `onDragStart` event is not passing the event object to the handler method. I have referred the [documentation of HTML5 Drag and Drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API), where it has shown how event object is passed to handler.

This is my code to implement the event Handler for `onDragStart` event.

```
//handler method
dragStartHandler(event) {
 console.log(event); // undefined
}

render() {
 return (
   <div draggable="true" 
    onDragStart={this.dragStartHandler(event)}></div>
 )
}
```

The handler is getting called but without the event object. My agenda is to capture the event object so that I can proceed further to bind data to the event, using the [DataTransfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) interface.

Please help me understand the behavior.

Thanks!

> **Update**

Not passing the event to the `dragStartHandler` method actually passes the event to the handler method. Its just the way react works to bind a method, unlike what is mentioned in the HTML5 DND documentation, seem not to work with react. The event which I got in the handler was wrapped up version of original Drag [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) as per html specs. This behavior just confused me as it was giving some [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object might be created by  react.

> **Solution** : Although the Proxy object has all the methods of original
>   Drag event, I realized it later. So you can use the new Proxy event
>   object as you did previously as native html element, with all previous 
>   behavior.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace

`onDragStart={this.dragStartHandler(event)}`

to

`onDragStart={this.dragStartHandler}`

You should pass a function to `onDragStart` property, (as for any other events-related property like `onClick`, `onMouseEnter` etc.), not result of the function invocation as you did. React.js will pass the event object as an argument to the handler function "under the hood". However, you must remember, that React.js creates a wrapper around native JavaScript event. Its name "SyntheticEvent". See [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html) for details. But, you can get access to a native event in the handler function (see the code below):

```
var Draggable = React.createClass({
    handleDrag(event) {
    console.log('react SyntheticEvent ==> ', event);
    console.log('nativeEvent ==> ', event.nativeEvent); //<- gets native JS event
  },

  render: function() {
    return (<div draggable="true" onDragStart={this.handleDrag}>
                Open console and drag me!
            </div>);
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Draggable />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Look at this example in action - https://jsfiddle.net/yrhvw0L0/2/

Comment: Hey @Mikhail, Have you gone through the documentation of Html5 drag drop I mentioned. It has event object passed, if you can see. The solution you have mentioned is already tried. Its not working

Comment: @Prabodh M I added link to jsfiddle. Look how it works. Then you write `onDragStart={this.dragStartHandler(event)}` you doing invocation immediately, on every trigger of "render" method. Your should pass function, react js will pass event object as argument to the function "under the hood".

Comment: @PrabodhM - You probably have a `this` issue as well.  either use arrow functions,  or bind handlers in the constructor, etc.  eg element property  `onDragStart={this.dragStartHandler.bind(this)}></div>`  and the function defined as `dragStartHandler = (event) => { ... } ` . or bound in the constructor.  But @Mikhail is right,  you want to pass a function,  not the invocation of a function (unless the invocation is returning a function, but that's probably not the case here)

Comment: Thanks @MikhailShabrikov. I already had that proxy object which is coming there, but was unable to figure it out, that it was wrapper over original html5 drag event !

Comment: @Prabodh M Yes, React.js adds a wrapper around native JavaScript event. Its name "SyntheticEvent". See docs for details - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html You can get access to a native event like this - `event.nativeEvent`. Look at my updated jsFiddle example - https://jsfiddle.net/yrhvw0L0/1/

Comment: @MikhailShabrikov : Woohoo, thats what I needed bro, thanks a lot ! Can you update the answer with the details, will be helpful to newbies like me. Thanks!